# YouTube iframe embed not starting in HD

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed, youtube-api

I'm trying to embed an HD YouTube video but no matter what I try, it only ever seems to load the 480p version.

According to YouTube, embedding an HD video is as simple as adding `hd=1` to the URL:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{videoId}?hd=1" width="960" height="720"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This, however, does not seem to be working, at least in my implementation of the `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="video-player" width="960" height="720" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{videoId}?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&showsearch=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The same is true with the Javascript API:

HTML:

```
<div id="video-player"></div>
```

JS:

```
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('video-player', {
            height: '720',
            width: '960',
            videoId: '{videoId}',
            playerVars: {
                'controls': 1,
                'autoplay': 1,
                'hd': 1
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player.playVideo();
    }
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Use this parameter:**

vq=hd1080

**Example:**

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/SzTdgE04uA8?vq=hd1080" width="853" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: To those wondering, this is still working over a year later, despite the parameter not appearing in either Google's supported list or deprecated list.

Comment: Unfortunately YouTube dropped the support for 1080p videos in October 2013. You can only get up to 720p now: http://googlesystem.blogspot.de/2013/10/youtube-drops-support-for-1080p-streams.html

Comment: Can't get this to autoplay in 1080p. Embedded dimensions are 940x529

Answer (score 27):

As per [this answer](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=0b0c92f515f342aa&hl=en) on the YouTube support forum:

> [The iframe embed] will attempt to "optimize" the experience and will work off
> of the dimensions of the embed player to choose what quality to play
> it back at by default.
>
> If the embed is much *smaller* than 1280x750, such as 853x510 or 640x390, it will play 480p or 360p, **regardless of whether the &hd=1** parameter is set.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

I changed the dimensions of the iframe to 1280x720 and the video loaded at 720p resolution.

So, basically the iframe embed mechanism is intelligent and only loads the closest resolution according to the size of the iframe.

Comment: Adding `vq=hd720` to the URL will do the trick, even when your iframe's dimensions are smaller.

The downscaled version of the 720p stream looks often nicer then the native 360p or 480p version, plus the audio is also better.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh, does this still work? Doesn't seem to force when I try it now. Are you using /embed or /v?

Comment: @MarcoMarsala: Did you ever find a solution for this on iPad?

Comment: Use &vq=1080 AND also the iframe size in pixel, set via CSS or width/height should be 1080... Otherwise iPad will not load the HD version (but computer does). See an example on the site I'm developing: http://www.metro-5.com videos will play at Full HD quality on computers (because I used vq=1080) but at poor quality in native Apple video player (because the frame height is only 320 and Apple ignores vq param by design), but you can change at runtime from the UI. They would play at better quality from the beginning if I set the iframe at higher height.

Answer (score 7):

There is a trick you can do.  Set the quality via JS.  Its not guaranteed, but works on my site (ggreplayz.com):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_quality

Example:

```
<iframe id="vid2" style="z-index: 1;" width="853" height="505" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $vid2Array[0];?>?enablejsapi=1&wmode=transparent&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
...
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {    
      player1 = new YT.Player('vid1', {
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady1
        }
      });
...
    function onPlayerReady1(event) { 
        player1.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
    }
...
```

Comment: Wow! It's work.
I've followed https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference.

Comment: This is a great answer. This is the only way to set video quality to hd720 while using YouTubeAPI

Answer (score 5):

`hd` parameter has been deprecated: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Deprecated_Parameters

Answer (score 2):

I use `&hd=1&vq=hd720` for achieve that. It loads the 720p version even if the player is smaller. I got this information from [this source](http://online-marketing-technologies.com/tools/youtube-embed-code-generator.html).

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late, but I just discovered it only looks at the height of the video player.

When I try to embed a video 1000px wide, but only 408 pixels high (2.35:1 matte) it selects 360p >:|

Comment: That makes sense since the resolution of the video is measured in height. 1280x720 is 720p and 1920x1080 is 1080p. Curiously, the next generation of HD is 4k, but that number is derived from its horizontal resolution.

Answer (score 1):

After spending more than 5hrs searching and testing all the answers, the below code works for me.
Using Xcode 5, iOS 7.0.4 and iPad mini2.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head>\
<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = yes, height = 640px, width = 360px\"/></head>\
<body style=\"background:#000;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">\
<iframe id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"640px\" height=\"360px\"\
src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?vq=hd1080\"\
frameborder=\"0\"/>\
</body></html>";

htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString,self.videoId, self.videoId];
[self.videoPlayerView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];

}
```

The only important thing here is the aspect ratio that you set in your iframe (**" width=\"640px\" height=\"360px\"**), which are basically the ratios of 1280*720. And then set the same size for your UIWebView. 
Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Mine wasn't working at all. I tried everything including all these parameters

```
&hd=1&vq=hd720&quality=high
```

But it didn't work until I added this parameter:

```
&version=3
```