# Embed YouTube videos in HD with new embed code (small video player)

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

The newest YouTube embed code will only play videos in HD if the embedded player is large. My embedded player is small. Is there a way to make it play in HD anyway?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8057047/669611.

Comment: I think not. That question was referring to videos in general, where it was revealed that YouTube determines HD or not based on embedded player size. My question concerns how to get around that, and have HD video on a small player.

Comment: Well, while you wait for an answer, I suggest you read the portion of this page: http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178264 labeled "Deciding whether to use High Definition (HD)."

Comment: That page is very out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a little out of date, seeing as the pictures from the website I found this from* don't match up with what's currently on YouTube, but heck, it's worth a shot, right?

In short, you have to use the old embed code with some minor changes:

```
<object width="640" height="360">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?hl=en_US&rel=0&hd=1"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?hl=en_US&rel=0&hd=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

Of course, you should swap out VIDEO_ID with your desired video's ID. Hope this helps.

Seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/h9eRM/

*[Link directly to and embed HD YouTube videos](http://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/link-directly-to-and-embed-hd-youtube-videos) by http://www.h3xed.com

Comment: @max did you get a chance to try it out?