# Youtube video always stream low resolution in iFrame?

Tags: ios, iframe, youtube

I am using an iFrame for embedding a youtube video in my iOS/iPad application, application displays video nicely, but the problem is, it always streams a low resolution video, I did try all of the "hd=1" of "vq=large" and a few more things. it's not helping. Any help will be greatly appreciable.

Comment: Hi Anup, please check if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/14437407/1880431

Answer (score 1):

1. go to the Share tab below the video, then the Embed tab

[image]

copy the html provided and paste into your site’s editor, should look something like this:

```
<iframe width=”560″ height=”315″ src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/RrphKwWOfcg?rel=0″ frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

then add the magic html additions (in bold)

```
<iframe width=”560″ height=”315″ src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/RrphKwWOfcg?rel=0&amp;vq=hd1080” frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

(or ?rel=0&vq=hd720 for 720p)