WkWebView: YouTube iframe low video quality on "Mac (Designed for iPad)"
I have a simple WkWebView with a YouTube iframe embedded.
I get high quality on

iPad simulator
physical iPhone

I only get low quality on

iPhone simulator
Mac (Designed for iPad)

I tried ?quality=high and setting the width & height to something larger, but that never seems to affect anything.
struct TestView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let html = """
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=YES">
        <iframe
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_7vP9vsnYPc" />
    """

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) { }
}

How can I fix this so that "Mac (Designed for iPad)" gets the higher quality?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001299/how-to-embed-high-quality-video-with-new-youtube-iframe-style-code doesn't work?

@Larme sadly it doesn’t, that’s where the quality=high is coming from that I mentioned.

And &vq=hd1080 doesn't work too? I might be a typo on the question, but it's said that you tried ?quality=hight instead of ?quality=high

@Larme ah, that is indeed a typo. None of these work sadly.

The best solution I could come up with, though not ideal, is to replace the user agent. On ‘Mac (Designed for iPad)’, an iPad user agent is used. Using the Mac one enables higher quality, even though it still doesn’t appear in the quality selection. However, this also breaks the fullscreen option.
I'm trying to do this slightly more dynamic:
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    
    if ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac {
        let userAgent = webView.value(forKey: "userAgent") as? String
        let newUserAgent = createCustomMacOsUserAgent(userAgent)
        webView.customUserAgent = newUserAgent // < set a Mac user agent
    }

    return webView
}

func createCustomMacOsUserAgent(_ userAgent: String?) -> String {
    var osVersion = "17_5"
    var webKitVersion = "605.1.15"

    if let userAgent = userAgent {
        if let range = userAgent.range(of: "AppleWebKit/") {
            let webKitVersionStart = userAgent[range.upperBound...]
            if let endRange = webKitVersionStart.range(of: " ") {
                webKitVersion = String(webKitVersionStart[..<endRange.lowerBound])
            }
        }
        if let range = userAgent.range(of: "CPU OS ") {
            let osVersionStart = userAgent[range.upperBound...]
            if let endRange = osVersionStart.range(of: " ") {
                osVersion = String(osVersionStart[..<endRange.lowerBound]).replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: ".")
                print("osVersion", osVersion)
            }
        }
    }

    return "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/\(webKitVersion)"
        + " (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/\(osVersion) Safari/\(webKitVersion)"
}

